# Implicit copy constructor and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I know this kind of question has been asked many times, and I've read different answers about it, as well as some parts of the ISO standard.
But still, I need **a few clarifications** about the exact behaviour expected by the C++ standard.

Assuming this:

```
class A
{
    public:

        A( void ) {}
        A( const A & a ) {}
};

class B: public A
{
    public:

        B( void ) {}
        B( const B & b ) {}
};
```

I know that calling the copy constructor of the `B` class won't call the copy constructor of the `A` class, and that we can use an **initialisation list** in order to do it properly.

I also know about using `using` in order to inherit constructors.

But what does the standard exactly mandates about a derived class which does not provides explicitly a copy constructor, while the base class does:

```
class A
{
    public:

        A( void ) {}
        A( const A & a ) {}
};

class B: public A
{};
```

I always thought the compiler would implicitly define a copy constructor for class `B`, thus hiding the copy constructor of class `A`, which won't be called.

However, looks like it's not the case, and the the `A` copy constructor is called.
Compiling with Clang on OS X 10.10.

So is this something mandatory, or something that can be implementation defined, meaning we should not rely on this behaviour?

In the C++ standard, I've found the following, but it's clearly not crystal-clear to me:

> An inheriting constructor for a class is implicitly defined when it is
>   odr-used (3.2) to create an object of its class type (1.8). An
>   implicitly-defined inheriting constructor performs the set of
>   initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written
>   inline constructor for that class with a mem-initializer-list whose
>   only mem-initializer has a mem-initializer-id that names the base
>   class denoted in the nested-name-specifier of the using-declaration
>   and an expression-list as specified below, and where the
>   compound-statement in its function body is empty (12.6.2).

I would really enjoy a clarification on it, in accordance with the standard, and also with multiple inheritance in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor (emphasis mine):

> **Implicitly-defined copy constructor**
>
> If the implicitly-declared copy constructor is neither deleted nor
> trivial, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and
> compiled) by the compiler if odr-used. For union types, the
> implicitly-defined copy constructor copies the object representation
> (as by std::memmove). For non-union class types (class and struct),
> the constructor performs **full member-wise copy of the object's bases
> and non-static members**, in their initialization order, using direct
> initialization.

So it seems that compiler generated copy constructor will call the base copy constructor just as it calls the copy constructors of the members.

Comment: And to add, inheriting constructors have nothing to do with it at all, because copy constructors are never inherited, and inherited constructors don't prevent a proper copy constructor from being generated.